# Symfony datatransfomers json to array for choice type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have a mapped fields 'days' in my entity that contains some json:

```
{"monday":1,"tuesday":1,"wednesday":1,"thursday":1,"friday":1,"saturday":0,"sunday":0}
```

And i want to render it in some checkboxes in my form.

So i mapped this fields in my form, and add some datatransformers to transform this json to array.

But nothing render. I did not find anything about this specific case: datatransformers mapped field to array for choice type.

Here is my action in controler:

```
/**
    public function indexAction(Request $request, ScolariteManager $scolariteManager)
    {
        $scolarite = $scolariteManager->find(2276);
        $form = $this->createForm(Toto::class, $scolarite);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        return $this->render('AciaProAppBundle:Default:index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Here is my form:

```
<?php

namespace AciaPro\AppBundle\Form\Type;

use AciaPro\AppBundle\Entity\Scolarite;
use AciaPro\AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\TransformToto;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class Toto extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var TransformToto
     */
    private $transformToto;

    public function __construct(TransformToto $transformToto)
    {
        $this->transformToto = $transformToto;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('joursCantineArray', ChoiceType::class, [
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
        ])->addModelTransformer($this->transformToto)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Scolarite::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is my datatransformers:

```
<?php

namespace AciaPro\AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use AciaPro\AppBundle\Entity\Scolarite;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class TransformToto implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function transform($data)
    {
        /** @var Scolarite $data */
        $data->setJoursCantineArray(json_decode($data->getJoursCantine(), true));

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function reverseTransform($data)
    {

        /** @var Scolarite $data */
        $data->setJoursCantine(json_encode($data->getJoursCantineArray()));

        return $data;
    }
}
```

And here is my entity

```
<?php

namespace AciaPro\AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Scolarite
 */
class Scolarite
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id_scolarite;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $jours_cantine;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $jours_cantine_array;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdScolarite()
    {
        return $this->id_scolarite;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id_scolarite
     * @return Scolarite
     */
    public function setIdScolarite(int $id_scolarite)
    {
        $this->id_scolarite = $id_scolarite;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getJoursCantine()
    {
        return $this->jours_cantine;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $jours_cantine
     * @return Scolarite
     */
    public function setJoursCantine(string $jours_cantine)
    {
        $this->jours_cantine = $jours_cantine;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJoursCantineArray()
    {
        return $this->jours_cantine_array;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $jours_cantine_array
     * @return Scolarite
     */
    public function setJoursCantineArray(array $jours_cantine_array)
    {
        $this->jours_cantine_array = $jours_cantine_array;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

And the twig:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.joursCantineArray) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
</body>
</html>
```

The resutl display the label and nothing else

Comment: So what have you tried?  Have you confirmed the transformer is being called?

Comment: Well, I confirmed it went into the transformer that the json was transformed to array and that the entity contains what I needed.